# NSInvalidArgumentException after manually triggering seque

Tags: ios, objective-c, segue, xcode-storyboard

I'm in the "awesome" position to have to support someone else's code even though before this project I have never worked in objective C or made iOS apps, so please excuse me if I'm doing something really obvious or stupid.

I needed a new view controller with a custom class. First I drew the view on my storyboard. Then I created a new class which I derived off of UIViewController. Then, I set the view's custom class to this new class I made. I hooked up the single button on the view to the code so I could make it close the view, then I made a (manual/modal) segue so I could call this new view from my main menu. All of this should be hooked up fine because I've used it before, but I'll show you how I call the segue anyway:

```
[self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"ScoreCard" sender:self];
```

Now, my problem is that when I press the button to run the above, I get the following error:

> -[Scores _setViewDelegate:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x9b4c460

Scores is the name of my custom UIViewController class. Its .h file looks pretty simple for now:

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface Scores : UIViewController

- (IBAction)goBack:(id)sender;

@end
```

The .m file doesn't do anything besides what Xcode put in there by default and my implementation of goBack:

```
- (IBAction)goBack:(id)sender
{
    [self dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES];
}
```

Does anyone know what I'm forgetting? I successfully added another view controller yesterday in the same way and that one works just fine. Why doesn't this one?

Comment: post the content of the prepareForSegue method (in the view controller that is performing the segue)

Comment: What type of segue did you create in the storyboard (push, modal)? It's unclear why you are both dismissing and popping a view controller in your goBack method.

Comment: @SPA: my `prepareForSegue` method contains nothing related to this particular segue as I only want it to be executed, nothing needs to be prepared. @rdelmar: It's a modal segue. I copy/pasted this way of closing it from what my predecessor did somewhere. I take it I have to remove the pop? Though I don't think it's related to the problem I have right now.

Comment: You definitely ned to remove the pop then. Try it and see if that fixes the problem. Also, do you have a property called viewDelegate in Scores? I don't see where that error can come from given the code you posted.

Comment: Removing it sadly didn't fix it, but thanks for the tip anyway. It's not the first strange thing I've found in this code base. I posted the complete header file for Scores above, the .m file only contains implementations for `initWithNibName`, `viewDidLoad`, `didReceiveMemoryWarning` and the close button I made and posted. These methods were all generated by Xcode and do nothing more than call their super class.

Comment: Looking at other questions, it seems that other people got this error when they changed the class of the controller's view instead of the controller itself. In IB, select the controller and the view and check their classes.

Comment: I could have sworn I had checked that. Turns out both my View and its ViewController had the same custom class checked. Thanks! Can you post it as an answer so I can give you a well-earned rep boost?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error that you're getting, -[Scores _setViewDelegate:]: unrecognized selector..., seems to be caused by setting the class of a UIView to a class that's not a subclass of UIView. Make sure that you've set the class for your view controller, not the view, to your custom class.