# Storyboard - ViewController setViewDelegate : unrecognized selector

Tags: ios, objective-c, delegates, storyboard

I have an app that is based on Storyboard. Each of the view controllers (in Storyboard) has its own custom class (with .h an .m files).

Those controllers inherit from UIViewController. When any of the controllers (except the first one) is to be called, I get an error:

> [controller _setViewDelegate:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x8ab94e0.

What could cause this error?

Here is part of OptionsController, which is one of the problematic controllers :

```
#import "OptionsController.h"

@implementation OptionsController

- (id)init
{
    if (self = [super init]) {
        // Initialization code
    }
    return self;
}

-(void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated
{
    [self.musicSwitch setOn:[[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults]objectForKey:@"music"] boolValue]];
    [self.soundSwitch setOn:[[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults]objectForKey:@"sound"] boolValue]];
}
```

Comment: Have you tried setting a breakpoint on `[UIViewController -_setViewDelegate:]`?  You can view the stack trace and see why it's getting called.

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19982332/nsinvalidargumentexception-after-manually-triggering-seque/19983494#19983494

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In either your header file or your storyboard, you're incorrectly declaring `OptionsController` as a subclass of `UIView` instead of `UIViewController`.

Comment: In OptionsController.h, I have something like this : @interface OptionsController : UIViewController

Comment: And in your storyboard?

Comment: In storyboard also UIViewController

Answer (score 0):

Hard to say. The method name _setViewDelegate is almost certainly and internal method.

Post the code that creates a new view controller and presents it.